# Where can I find a hosting service with R?

Tags: r

Are there any traditional (cheap, shared) web hosting services that have R on the server?

UPDATE: I went with Dreamhost on this one. I first tried to build R on a shared server, but I needed their support staff installed some packages (ex gfortran). After some struggles, I was able to get R built from source with the exception of the x11 headers, which means that graphics couldn't be saved using the png() function. Not a great resuls, so I upgraded to the private server package.  Their private server gives you full root access to a Debian server, so installing R was as easy as executing `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`.  Still very affordable for a pet project, plus they don't care about long running processes, just memory usage (which is how their private server plan is priced).

Comment: I doubt it;would be nice, nevertheless.

Comment: I would ask webfaction (http://www.webfaction.com/) - they seem to be open to installing things on their servers for clients.

Comment: Good lead, thanks! I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: webfaction allows you to install anything in your home directory, but they may not be happy with you running CPU/memory intensive processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a tarball or svn checkout of the source in the unix shell and just do the ole ./configure; make game

Comment: using a cheapo shared web server, its doubtful the hosting service would let me just insall R on the server due to both security and from a use of resources standpoint

Comment: Define cheapo ... I use Dreamhost which IMO is pretty affordable and have run R from the shell.  You don't have to "install" it in terms of /usr/local or whatever, just build it in your directory and fire it up.

Comment: Hmmm, Dreamhost looks promising with their shell access. My only question is, I wonder what they do if someone executes a command to generate a bazillion random variables?

Comment: Honestly I haven't run anything heavy enough to really cause them issues. I believe that they don't really care what you're doing as long as you're not causing a lot of trouble, but at the end of the day most of their customers are doing webhosting so aren't doing too much.  I do know that they try to work with people that are causing problems, and not just say "Sorry, go away".  The other limitation are servers and persistent processes, but I've had (low cpu using) processes running for a while, I think they have a kill set up for processes after a week.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Amazon's elastic computing cloud. A basic server with R that can host as many users as you like runs for about ten cents an hour.

Another option is [monkeyanalytics.com](http://www.monkeyanalytics.com/) which allows you to run R on their server. It also uses Amazon EC2 as a backend but you don't have to deal with launching or shutting down instances.

Comment: I guess I should clarify. By traditional I mean 'web' hosting.  +1 for the cool think though.