# Integrating R with existing C# website

Tags: r, web-services

We have existing website built in C# and hosted on a shared Windows server. The aim is to build a simple app within existing website that would take in some data, entered by user, and process it using some R scripts (some statistics) and publish the output on the website in a static (dynamic?) format.

Basic requirements:

1. Secure
2. Relatively inexpensive
3. Low maintenance requirements

What are the existing options?

- Does Microsoft offer an out-of-the-box solution, given their heavy activity (Revolution R)?
- [R.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community/) could be used if the hosting company (private hosting) allowed R installation on their server (website hosted there). I’m not sure how good this solution would be, however.
- What are the other options apart from [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/)?

<sub>Old entry on similar issue on SO: [Where can I find a hosting service with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523528/where-can-i-find-a-hosting-service-with-r)</sub>

Comment: If you're just sending data to R and getting data back why not use `fiery` or `plumber` to make a simple REST interface you can call from the existing site. You can even run said REST server on the same box (on the non-public interface).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Sadly, I don't know any of the terminology you used. If you could expand it and post as an answer (please be somewhat detailed so I can replicate/use it, possible references could be useful (manual etc.)), I would greatly appreciate your effort.

Comment: You might want to have a look at sql server 2017 and it's R capabilities

Comment: @HerberL, thanks for your suggestion. There is lot of information to be look at and understand. I was hopping someone some suggesting solution would also post somewhat detailed information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) app can absolutely be integrated into a webpage, typically as an iframe hosted by [shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io/), and embedded into your website. See [Shiny homepage](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) for an example. You can see some pointers in [Embedding a Shiny application in a html document](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/shiny-discuss/2VwEWXYJwYs) on Google Groups.

A solution more in line with what was asked is to use a server application like [RServe](https://github.com/SurajGupta/RserveCLI2) to facilitate communication between a running R session and a .NET/C# application. Since RServe allows for remote connections, it can be used by an existing website, with the RServer running on a different server.

Comment: So embedding with iframe, let's see what other options are available. Thanks.

Comment: this really isnt an answer and should be moved to the comment section (where someone already made this point a whole 4 hours before this was posted)

Comment: shinyapps.io have its limit. OP probably want to host the server. Though shiny server doesn't support windows now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to fire up an amazon ec2 windows image.  install R.  use R.NET.  done.